# BoxLayout ignores setYAlighment

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, boxlayout

Here is a function:

```
/**
 * Creates an instance of a JLabel with the given arguments
 * @param text The text to be displayed on the Label
 * @param font The font of the label
 * @param bold set to true if you want the label's text to be bold
 * @param fontSize The size of the font to be rendered
 * @param alignment An alignment (E.g. CENTER_ALIGNMENT)
 * @param verticleAlignment an optional argument to allow one to choose the Y alignment
 * **/
public JLabel createLabel(String text, String font, boolean bold, int fontSize, float alignment, float...verticleAlignment){
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
    label.setFont(new Font(font, bold ? Font.BOLD : Font.PLAIN, fontSize));


    label.setAlignmentX(alignment);
    if(verticleAlignment.length > 0){
        label.setAlignmentY(verticleAlignment[0]);
    }
    return label;
}
```

For some reason, no matter what I enter in the varArg verticleAlignment, it doesn't actually apply?

```
add(createLabel("ChatBytes™ - Do not steal.", "Arial", false, 12, CENTER_ALIGNMENT, BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT));
```

Can anyone see a reason why it would ignore the setYAlignment part of my function?

[image: This is how it renders]

Comment: Read [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment) from the Swing tutorial on `Using Box Layout` for a detailed explanation on how alignment works. If you still need help then post a `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'll read up on that, can you explain the acronym SSCCE please?

Comment: google, google, bing, bing :-)

Comment: the bounty won't help until you show a SSCCE ..

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: This question has annoyed, what an uneasy bunch of people I've been unfortunate enough to have stumble upon my question. I've found the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
    add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

to create a vertical space that pushes the component to the bottom of the JFrame

Comment: +1 for `createVerticalGlue()`; please consider adding an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach, such as the one shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18805146/230513).

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, consider a [nested layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513). In the example below, the relevant label is added to the `SOUTH` area of a `BorderLayout`, the default for `JFrame`, and a placeholder for your login panel is added to `CENTER`. Examine the resize behavior of each approach for suitability.

Addendum: *I hope to [learn] why the* `setAlignmentY()` *is being ignored.*

As noted in [*How to Use BoxLayout: Box Layout Features*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#features), "When a `BoxLayout` lays out components from top to bottom, … any extra space appears at the bottom of the container." This explains your original [observation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18744960/230513) and correct [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18803764/230513).

In the API, note that [`setAlignmentX()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX%28float%29) "Sets the the vertical alignment," and [`setAlignmentY()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentY%28float%29) "Sets the the horizontal alignment." In this context, *vertical* means the vertical axis of a top-to-bottom layout, such as `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`, while *horizontal* means the horizontal axis of a left-to-right layout, such as `BoxLayout.X_AXIS`. In [*How to Use BoxLayout: Fixing Alignment Problems*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment), [`BoxAlignmentDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/index.html#BoxAlignmentDemo) contrasts the two. In a left-to-right layout, pictured below, `setAlignmentY()` is used to adjust vertical positioning relative to the horizontal layout axis. In a top-to-bottom layout, such as yours, `setAlignmentY()` simply has no effect.

[image: setAlignmentY]

---

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805146/230513 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(createLogin(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JLabel admonition = new JLabel("ChatBytes™—Do not steal.", JLabel.CENTER);
        f.add(admonition, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createLogin() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Existing CHATBYTES login panel.");
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC, 24f));
        label.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 20));
        p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(36));
        p.add(label);
        p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(144));
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```