# How to make Components align to the TOP in JPanel with BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, alignment, boxlayout

I'm developing a game called GalaxyWar, and I am trying to make a map selection menu. I found a problem that when I am using a BoxLayout with `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` on a JPanel with `setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT)`, the subcomponents (JPanel's) with assigned size, take up the entire height of the panel (all together), instead of the assigned height!

Here is my code:

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(160, 11, 452, 307);
    add(scrollPane);

    mapContainer = new JPanel();
    mapContainer.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    mapContainer.setAlignmentY(JPanel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    mapContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mapContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(mapContainer);

    JPanel demoPanel = new JPanel();
    demoPanel.setLayout(null);
    demoPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    demoPanel.setSize(50, 100);
    mapContainer.add(demoPanel);
```

I've researched on this for long, but couldn't find any solutions so far.

Comment: 1) `scrollPane.setBounds(160, 11, 452, 307);` What is that supposed to achieve?  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).  .. (cont)

Comment: .. (cont) 2) `demoPanel.setSize(50, 100);` See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 3) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: My scrollPane is placed on another JPanel with absolute layout, thats why I used .setBounds() method!

Comment: *"My scrollPane is placed on another JPanel with absolute layout"*  Then they both need fixing (as opposed to justifying).

Comment: `I Researched alot of websites, finding no help,` - all the websites recommend that you should NOT use a null layout.

Comment: Also, review the relevant section of the tutorial, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18805146/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check out

```
setPreferredSize() 
setMaximumSize()
setMinimumSize()
```

set all 3 to the same value.

If it still doesn't work, you can try to put the panel, of which you are trying to set the size to fixed, inside another panel.

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)